# How to start loop fresh for every call of function

Tags: c#

I am trying to stop the loop when called the function.suppose first i call the function one loop is running and again called that function i need to break the first called loop and start the loop fresh again.

```
 public void HitTimer(int leagueid,int dposition,int teamid,int round)
    {
        //if (_hubContext == null)
        //{
        //  _hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
        // }


        int m = 1;

        for (int k = 1; k < 91; k++)
        {

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (k == 90)
            {
                AutoAddDraftPlayer(leagueid, dposition,teamid,round); 

            }
            else if (_hubContext != null)
            {

                    _hubContext.Clients.All.broadcastTime(90 - k, leagueid, teamid, round);



                //hubContext.Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).broadcastTime(90 - k);
                //Clients.Caller.broadcastTime(90 - k);
            }
            m++;
        }
    }
```

my code is above and let me know how to solve

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor this to be `Task` based and then use a cancellation token to cancel the first task if the method is called again. The details of how to do all of this is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation

```
static tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
static CancellationToken ct = tokenSource.Token;
static Task task = null;

public void HitTimer(int leagueid,int dposition,int teamid,int round)
{
    if (task != null)
        tokenSource.Cancel();

    try
    {
        if (task != null)
            task.Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        foreach (var v in e.InnerExceptions)
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message + " " + v.Message);
    }

    task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoLoop(leagueid, dposition, teamid, round), tokenSource.Token)
}

public void DoLoop(int leagueid,int dposition,int teamid,int round)
{
    int m = 1;
    for (int k = 1; k < 91; k++)
    {
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            break;
        }

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        if (k == 90)
        {
            AutoAddDraftPlayer(leagueid, dposition,teamid,round); 

        }
        else if (_hubContext != null)
        {

                _hubContext.Clients.All.broadcastTime(90 - k, leagueid, teamid, round);



            //hubContext.Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).broadcastTime(90 - k);
            //Clients.Caller.broadcastTime(90 - k);
        }
        m++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi brimble2010,i got null reference exception for the first time tast is null and its goes to task.wait then it return exception.please give me the solution

Comment: I've edited my answer to do the null check. This is just some example code, I've not tried to run it but rather provided it for reference. Have a look at the link that I gave to see a working example.